# "Import Statistics" Fails To Run

Tags: python, module, statistics, package, sublimetext

When I use IDLE the code "import statistics" runs, however when I use sublimetext while other packages, such as matplotlib, can be imported I cannot import the statistics module. It gives me this error code:

```
import math
import matplotlib
import statistics
```

I expect nothing to happen on the screen, but in the command line it spits out. Note that the first two lines of code did work.

```
 ImportError: No module named statistics
[Finished in 1.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Ivan/Desktop/Math file.py"]
[dir: /Users/Ivan/Desktop]
[path:     /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the command prompt.

Type

```
pip3 install update
```

If that doesn't work try

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then type

```
pip3 install statistics
```

at the command prompt.

This has solved my similar problems in the past :)

Comment: Terminal now says  "Successfully installed docutils-0.14 statistics-1.0.3.5". However, I have run into a message saying "You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command." I tried running the "pip install --upgrade pip" code but this just gives an error message. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have that same thing happen, but I'm pretty certain it will work now, try importing it and see what error you get, then enter that file path through your finder or document app (depending on device)

Comment: Aha I figured it out use "pip3 install --upgrade pip" instead of just pip, this worked for me and solved a bunch of old things