# How to fix import errors with in-built python libraries?

Tags: python, statistics, importerror

I am having problems with importing the python statistics library into my program. Whenever I write `import statistics` at the top and try to run the code, it gives me an import error:
"No module named statistics".

I am using python 3.8 inside a virtualenv and I checked the python version using the terminal. I am using sublime text as my code editor.

I also tried importing the random library, and it worked without problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Import Statistics" Fails To Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965561/import-statistics-fails-to-run)

Answer (score 0):

For import errors you can use "try" to catch thsi errors and print a message o make another action if occurs the error:

```
try:
    import some_module_not_exist
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
    # DO some things
```

Replace the general Exception for the original exception on your code.

Comment: I think the question is more aimed at fixing the import error rather than simply ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

`statistics` is not visible from inside your virtualenv. You need to install it inside the virtualenv.

Activate your virtualenv:

```
source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

Install `statistics`:

```
pip install statistics
```

Also make sure you're running your program using the python executable living inside that virtualenv, otherwise it won't work.